# how to set Number from 0 to increment 1,2,,... etc for combine dictionary

Tags: c#

I have 2 dictionaries where `Number = 0` for all items,

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, Test>
{
    { "Key1", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name1" } },
    { "Key2", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name2" } },
    { "Key3", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name3" } }
};

var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, Test>
{
    { "Key1", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name1" } },
    { "Key4", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name4" } }
};
```

Now after eliminating duplicate key/value pairs, in combined dictionary result I want to set Number = 1, 2, 3,... how to do this?

```
var combine = dict1.Union(dict2)
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .Select(grp => grp.First())
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: `combine[<SomeKey>].Number = <SomeNumber>;`

Comment: i need to have for all item

Comment: Does the keys have number (Key1...) for real or that was just an example. You want to set Key1 to Number = 1...?

Comment: "_i need to have for all item_". Sure. Nothing will stop you from iterating over the dictionary (or the keys of the dictionary) and set the numbers for all items. Doing this would be far, far easier and simpler than what it would have taken you to come up with the Linq construct in your question...

Comment: I have 4 items in combine dictionary, so I want number 1 to 4

Comment: Do you mean you want to count the amount of duplicates? For example `Key1` would have a `Number` of 2, and the rest 1?

Comment: A dictionary is unordered so there is no gurantee that Key1 will get number=1. Unless you explicitly specify the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;
var combine = dict1.Union(dict2)
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => new Test() { Number = ++i, Name = kvp.First().Value.Name });
```

It should give you this:

```
{ "Key1", new Test { Number = 1, Name = "Name1" } },
{ "Key2", new Test { Number = 2, Name = "Name2" } },
{ "Key3", new Test { Number = 3, Name = "Name3" } }
{ "Key4", new Test { Number = 4, Name = "Name4" } }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
var n = 0;
```

and then do it functionally but not very efficiently *in your case*. The function will select all items from your dictionary and create a new collection with updated values, which is then converted to a dictionary.

```
var newDict = dict2.Select(d => new Test { Number = ++n, Name = d.Value[1].Name }).ToDictionary();
```

Or with a good old loop:

```
foreach(var d in dict2)
{
    d.Value[0].Number = n++;
}
```

As suggested by the comment. If you want to start off with 0, use

```
n++;
```

if with 1, use

```
++n;
```

Comment: Good use of Linq, but you should explain it a bit for those who may not understand it. Also consider doing `++n` instead of `n++` since he wants the numbering to start at 1 supposedly (or make `n` 1 as initial value)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the keys

```
int n = 1;
foreach (string key in combine.Keys) {
   combine[key].Number = n++;
}
```

The keys are not returned in order. If you want to number them in order:

```
int n = 1;
var orderedKeyValuePairs = combine
    .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
foreach (var kvp in orderedKeyValuePairs) {
    kvp.Value.Number = n++;
}
```

Note that you can only access the `Number` like this if `Test` is a reference type (`class`). If `Test` was a `struct`, you would have to re-assign the whole struct because the dictionary would return a copy of the value.

The optional `StringComparer` argument allows you to specify different string comparison modes:

```
Ordinal, OrdinalIgnoreCase, CurrentCulture, CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
```

If you want to sort by name:

```
int n = 1;
var orderedValues = combine.Values
    .OrderBy(v => v.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
foreach (var v in orderedValues) {
    v.Number = n++;
}
```

Looping over the key-value-pairs or values also has the advantage that you can change the value directly, whereas when looping through the keys (as in my first code snippet), you must look up the dictionary, which is less performing.

Comment: `dict1[key].Number = n++;` I believe he's asking for no?

Comment: But the keys are strings... The `OrderBy` might not give the desired result.

Comment: Keys, are strings, values are objects of type Test {int Number, string Name}

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to combine dictionaries, and then assign to `Number` the count of duplicate items.

You might consider putting all the dictionaries into a list and iterating over each item and putting it in a combined result dictionary. If the item already exists in the result then increment the `Number` property.

Initial setup:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, Test>
{
    { "Key1", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name1" } },
    { "Key2", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name2" } },
    { "Key3", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name3" } }
};

var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, Test>
{
    { "Key1", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name1" } },
    { "Key4", new Test { Number = 0, Name = "Name4" } }
};

// Put the dictionaries you want to combine into one list: 
var all = new List<Dictionary<string, Test>>();
all.Add(dict1);
all.Add(dict2);

// Declare result dictionary
var combine = new Dictionary<string, Test>();
```

Set up is done, this is the main loop you want:

```
foreach (var dict in all)
{
    foreach (var kvp in dict)
    {
        if (combine.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        {
            combine[kvp.Key].Number++;
        }
        else
        {
            combine.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Interactive shell output:

```
Dictionary<string, Submission#0.Test>(4) { 
    { "Key1", Submission#0.Test { Name="Name1", Number=1 } }, 
    { "Key2", Submission#0.Test { Name="Name2", Number=0 } }, 
    { "Key3", Submission#0.Test { Name="Name3", Number=0 } }, 
    { "Key4", Submission#0.Test { Name="Name4", Number=0 } } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of Select extension which provides index as well ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__))

```
var combine = dict1.Union(dict2)
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .Select((grp,index) => new { Key = grp.Key, Value = new Test { Number = index+1, Name = grp.First().Name}})
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```